# Why does dosfsck truncate files?

Tags: linux, fat32, fsck

I'm having a quite well known issue, but unfortunately I have a little lack of knowledge here and hope to find a better insight here.

So, I have a corrupt USB stick with a FAT32 file system. I made a clone with `ddrescue` and ran `testdisk`. A partition was found (phew!), so I created a loop device with `losetup -f -P USB_clone.img` and mounted it. So far so good, now the problem begins: all files are found with as it seems correct size (`ls -al`), but when I tried to copy a file I got an I/O error. So I umounted the partition again and ran `dosfsck -l -r -v /dev/loop1p1`. Some files could be recovered, but most of the files are repaired in a quite interesting way:

```
  File size is 27589006 bytes, cluster chain length is 32768 bytes.
  Truncating file to 32768 bytes.
```

This results in, well, truncated files; this is obviously not what I want...

So this leads me to some questions:

1. What happens here? It seems that the file sizes can be detected correctly, but something is completely wrong in the, hm, well, what? Maybe partition table? Why is `dosfsck` unable to fix this when the filename and the file size can be detected correctly?
2. And of course more important: is there any way to recover these files?

If you need further information just request them!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the partition table make sense? Use `fdisk` on the image.

Comment: People tend to misunderstand the purpose of `fsck`. It does not attempt to rescue your files, it only attempts to make the filesystem work again. It will sacrifice any data to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good explanation of FAT filesystem fragmentation at [Quora: How does the operating system handle the fragmented sectors in fat32 format to recovery the complete data?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-operating-system-handle-the-fragmented-sectors-in-fat32-format-to-recovery-the-complete-data) by Irné Barnard.

> Each sector has a part at the back (or the front, whatever the detail
> design is - but somewhere inside that sector) … something stating
> “next sector at position X”. That’s in the design of all FAT based
> file systems, including FAT32. And it’s also the reason fragmentation
> makes file access slow on FAT.
>
> Here’s how it works:
>
> 1. You (or some program you’re running) sends the operating system a request to open the file.
> 2. The OS passes the request on to the file system.
> 3. The FS (FAT) checks the path + filename, finding the first folder in the path given.
> 4. It then reads it’s root folder table (i.e. the start of the drive’s folder hierarchy). This gives it a sector number for the first
>    folder in the path.
> 5. It then continues to read that folder’s table, matching it against the next folder in the path given. Repeating until it’s found the last
>    filename/foldername in the path.
> 6. This gives it the sector where the file starts, as well as the size of the file - so it knows when it’s found all its sectors (simple
>    addition of sector sizes).
> 7. It reads that first sector, checking its metadata (i.e. the pointer to the next sector).
> 8. Reads that one too, adds the sector’s data size to the already read count. If still less than file size, continues to next sector in
>    metadata and repeats.

The crux of it is that the files being truncated are probably fragmented. When a recovery program is going through the blocks and trying to find the next fragment it has decided not to trust where it thinks the next block is.

The rules and problems that `dosfsck` uses to compare and decide when to truncate are at https://linux.die.net/man/8/dosfsck and it is difficult to know why it is truncating without knowing what damage the disk suffered to begin with. If the FAT was wiped then it could be that it does not believe any of the clusters listed in the cluster chain are in use and you hit the rule `File contains bad or free clusters. The file is truncated.`

`dosfsck` is not a recovery tool. It is a repair tool that assumes the disk is basically "okay" to begin with.

You might want to look at running proper recovery tools such as `photorec` [which can recover far more than just photos](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or `testdisk` which can do [far more than just copying partitions](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).